# Ringtone is playing the default ringtone

Tags: android

This has been changed from the original post.

Basically what is happening is I have gotten this to display the ringtone in the ringtone list on the phone. It also selects it. In this code it plays the ringtone after it has been selected (I have taken it out to reduce the size). It seems to be playing the phones default ringtone. Any ideas why? Thanks

```
private void ringtone(int p){
    File newSoundFile = new File("/sdcard/media/ringtone", "raven.wav");
    Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.fs.hh/"+R.raw.raven);
    ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();
    AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;

    try {
           soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           soundFile=null;   
       }

       try {
          byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
          FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
          int i = fis.read(readData);

          while (i != -1) {
            fos.write(readData, 0, i);
            i = fis.read(readData);
          }

          fos.close();
          soundFile.close();
       } catch (IOException io) {
       }

       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "my ringtone");
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/wav");
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

       Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
       mCr.delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);

       Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);



      RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Soundboard.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);



}
```

I have also tried adding a / after ringtone and making it get the byte size. Neither have worked.

I have also tried this piece of code instead and it causes the same problem. It shows up selected in the notification section, but the sound being played is not the correct sound. It sounds like a default ringer.

```
private boolean setRingtone(int p){
    int ressound = whichSound(p); //The R.raw.sound
    String fileTitle = fileTitle(p); // sound
    String soundTitle = soundTitle(p); // Sound
    byte[] buffer=null;
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
    int size=0;

    try {
    size = fIn.available();
    buffer = new byte[size];
    fIn.read(buffer);
    fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    return false;
    }

    String path="/sdcard/media/notification";
    String filename=fileTitle+".wav";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
    save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
    save.write(buffer);
    save.flush();
    save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    return false;
    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, soundTitle);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/wav");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "HH");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    //Insert it into the database
    Uri newUri= this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);

    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
    this,
    RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
    newUri
    );

        return false;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what finally fixed it.

```
private boolean setRingtone(int p){
    int ressound = whichSound(p);
    String fileTitle = fileTitle(p);
    String soundTitle = soundTitle(p);
    byte[] buffer=null;
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
    int size=0;

    try {
    size = fIn.available();
    buffer = new byte[size];
    fIn.read(buffer);
    fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    return false;
    }

    String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/ringtone/";

    String filename=fileTitle+".wav";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
    save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
    save.write(buffer);
    save.flush();
    save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    return false;
    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, soundTitle);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/wav");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    //Insert it into the database
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);



    return false;
      }
```

In the path String by adding Environment.getExternatStorageDirectory().getPath() instead of just the sdcard it was actually able to play the sound  and work properly.

Comment: I've tried the code above, but continue to receive "FileNotFound" exceptions.  I'm testing on the emulator... does that make any difference?

Comment: @worked I don't believe the emulator can do ringtones like that.

Comment: It can, just needed to set the correct permissions, and give the sdcard an actual space amount.

Comment: @steven  thanks a lot! Works great! :)
I have a small doubt..may be dumb!
Can't we set ringtone directly without saving it to sdcard?
i.e. directly from raw file?

Answer (score 0):

> Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.packange.name/"+R.raw.raven);

"com.packange.name" should be the name of **your** package, I assume you haven´t called it like that. Hardcode your package name, or call `getPackageName()` from a proper context.

**Update:** You can get an uri out of your `newSoundFile` object, just do `Uri.fromFile( newSoundFile )`.

Comment: @steven: Thats still not your package name, is it? Did you actually call your package "com.package.name"??

Comment: Where should I be using that Uri.fromFile(newSoundFile)? I couldn't use it from the mUri right because then there wouldn't be anything actually sending this sound file in